# Is there a way to go from Gen<a> to Gen<a list> while specifying a bound?

Tags: f#, fscheck

```
module BirthdayLibrary = 
    type Birthday =
        { day   :int
          month :int }

module DataGen = 
    let birthdayGenerator (months:option<list<int>>) = 
        let monthGen = match months with
                       | Some m -> Gen.elements m
                       | None   -> FsCheck.Gen.choose(1,12)
        (fun m d -> { day   = d
                      month = m}:BirthdayLibrary.Birthday)
        <!> monthGen
        <*> FsCheck.Gen.choose(1,28)

    //I want this to have the signature Gen<BirthdayLibrary.Birthday list>
    let oneForEveryMonthGen = 
        [ for m in [1 .. 12] ->
            (fun mo -> birthdayGenerator (Some [mo]))]
```

Lets say I have something like the above. I have a birthday generator with the return type of Gen<BirthdayLibrary.Birthday>. You can optionally specify the month. What is the best way to go from a Gen<a> to a Gen<a list> WHILE specifying some constraint to item in the list's gen? I can think of ways to get <Gen<a> list>, which I don't think would work for composing a parent object that should contain a <list a> (which is the basis for this example). I can also think of a way to do Gen<Gen<a> list>, which I had composition problems with as well as all values in the list being the same. I saw Gen.arrayOf bit I can't think of how to get it to work with values for each item in the array.

Comment: I'll add an answer that gives you the signature you want as well as the constraint, but I must confess I don't fully understand what you're getting at with the composition problems.

Comment: By composition problems I meant that I was unable to unwrap a Gen<Gen<a> list> to use with an object that had a property of type <a list>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
module BirthdayLibrary = 
    type Birthday =
        { day   :int
          month :int }

module DataGen = 
    let birthdayGenerator (months:option<list<int>>) = 
        let monthGen = match months with
                       | Some m -> Gen.elements m
                       | None   -> FsCheck.Gen.choose(1,12)
        (fun m d -> { day   = d
                      month = m}:BirthdayLibrary.Birthday)
        <!> monthGen
        <*> FsCheck.Gen.choose(1,28)

    //I want this to have the signature Gen<BirthdayLibrary.Birthday list>
    let oneForEveryMonthGen = 
        [ for m in [1 .. 12] -> birthdayGenerator (Some [m])]
        |> Gen.sequence

let sample = DataGen.oneForEveryMonthGen |> Gen.sample 10 1
```

gives me:

> val sample : BirthdayLibrary.Birthday list list =   [[{day = 7;
>        month = 1;}; {day = 15;
>                      month = 2;}; {day = 13;
>                                    month = 3;}; {day = 14;
>                                                  month = 4;}; {day = 28;
>                                                                month = 5;};
>       {day = 9;
>        month = 6;}; {day = 28;
>                      month = 7;}; {day = 15;
>                                    month = 8;}; {day = 6;
>                                                  month = 9;}; {day = 21;
>                                                                month = 10;};
>       {day = 12;
>        month = 11;}; {day = 27;
>                       month = 12;}]]